# i18n works with Thymeleaf but not with MessageSource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, maven-3, thymeleaf

I am working with Spring MVC+Thymeleaf and getting the following exception when I tried to get a message from de the MessageSource: `NoSuchMessageException`

My configuration:

```
@Bean(name="messageSource")
    public MessageSource messageSource(){
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages");
        source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);    
        source.setDefaultEncoding( propWebEncoding );
        source.setCacheSeconds(0); /* check the last-modified timestamp */
        return source;
    }
```

My files are under:

```
src/main/resources/i18n/messages_es.properties
src/main/resources/i18n/messages_en.properties
```

My locale is “en”
When I use the message “myproperty.example” in HTML (Thymeleaf) it works fine but not when I try to get the message in my `@Controller` or `@Service` with:

`@Autowired MessageSource messageSource`;

And

```
messageSource.getMessage(“myproperty.example”, null, Locale.EN);
```

It raises `NoSuchMessageException` exception impossible to find … for locale ‘en’
This is all configured with maven and my i18n files are in the target folder under: 
`WEB-INF/classes/i18n/ [files]`

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem: I was working in two different contexts. I was calling MessageSource in the @Service tier (getRootConfigClasses) and it was configured in the ServletConfigClasses.

Solution: Only work in the root context (getRootConfigClasses)

Comment: it's correct, if you have more config classes, put this code in "root config". You can check it in class which extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer class.